# On github, how do I check that all the circleci optional jobs are done runnning?

Tags: github, circleci

tl;dr;

1. Does Github support a branch protection rule that waits for all optional CircleCI jobs to be done?
2. If not, how can I create a "final" (dummy) job in CircleCI that triggers once all optional jobs are done running?

---

I use a mono repo and I configured CircleCI to just run the tests on the modules that have changed. That works well, no issue there.

My issue is with github: I would like to put branch protection to disallow merging until all optional jobs are done running. Alas, Github doesn't seem to support that.

My challenge then becomes this: On CircleCI, how can I trigger a "final" job once all the optional jobs are done? I think I would be able to hook that final job check on Github.

Thanks!